# Add Dynamic Component to Shopping Cart in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-dynamic-components

I have a pizza creator App, which allows the user to customize his own pizza and add toppings to it, I want to be able to add these customized pizzas to a cart service and display it in Cart Component.

**Choice.component.ts**
here is the choice class where I create a dynamic pizza component with its selected toppings

```
export class ChoicesComponent implements OnInit{ @ViewChild('pizza', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })pizza:ViewContainerRef;

selectedToppings: string[];
toppings: string[];

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private cartService: CartService) {
    this.selectedToppings = [];
    this.toppings = [
        'anchovy',
        'bacon',
        'basil',
        'chili',
        'mozzarella',
        'mushroom',
        'olive',
        'onion',
        'pepper',
        'pepperoni',
        'prawn',
        'sweetcorn',
        'tomato'
    ];
}

// Method to add topping to an array selectedToppings and remove it.

selectToppings(topping) {
    // console.log(topping);
    if (this.selectedToppings.indexOf(topping) === -1) {
        this.selectedToppings.push(topping);
    } else {
        this.selectedToppings.splice(this.selectedToppings.indexOf(topping), 1);
    }
}

// Create the Pizza Dynamically and push the selectedToppings to it.

createPizza() {
    const pizzaFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PizzaComponent);
    const pizza = this.pizza.createComponent(pizzaFactory);
    this.selectedToppings = []; // we will empty the selectedToppings array every time before creating a new pizza
    pizza.instance.toppings = this.selectedToppings;
}
```

**Choice.component.html**

```
<div class="container"><div class="name" *ngFor="let topping of toppings">
<div (click)=selectToppings(topping)>
  <span class=" icon {{topping}}"></span>
  <span>
    {{topping}}
  </span>
</div></div></div><div class="createPizza"><button (click)=createPizza() class="btn btn-success text-align-center">Create Pizza</button></div><div #pizza></div><div class="checkout"><a href="/cart" class="btn btn-success">Proceed To Checkout</a></div>
```

**Cart.service.ts**

```
export class CartService {
// pizzaListChanged = new Subject<Pizza[]>();
public cartItemList: any = [];
public pizzaList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

constructor() {}

getPizzas() {
    return this.pizzaList.asObservable();
    // return this.cartItemList.slice();
}

setPizza(pizza: any) {
    this.cartItemList.push(...pizza);
    this.pizzaList.next(pizza);
}

addToCart(pizza: any) {
    this.cartItemList.push(pizza);
    this.pizzaList.next(this.cartItemList);
    // this.getTotalPrice();
    // console.log(this.cartItemList);
}

getTotalPrice(): number {
    let grandTotal = 0;
    this.cartItemList.map((a: any) => {
        grandTotal += a.total;
    });
    return grandTotal;
}

removeCartItem(pizza: any) {
    this.cartItemList.map((a: any, index: any) => {
        if (pizza.id === a.id) {
            this.cartItemList.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
}

removeAllCart() {
    this.cartItemList = [];
    this.pizzaList.next(this.cartItemList);
}
```

}

**pizza.component.ts**

```
export class PizzaComponent implements OnInit {
toppings: string[]; constructor(private cartService: CartService, private pizzaService: PizzaService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.getPizzas().subscribe((res) => {
        // this.toppings = res;
    });
}

getMyStyles(i) {
    const myStyles = {
        transform: this.translate(i)
    };
    return myStyles;
}

translate(i) {
    const x = -30 + Math.round(50 * Math.cos(i * (2 * Math.PI / 15))) + 'px';
    const y = 20 + Math.round(26 * Math.sin(i * (2 * Math.PI / 15))) + 'px';
    const val = `translate(${x}, ${y})`;
    return val;
}

// we need an array of the customized pizzas with its selectedToppings
addtoCart(topping: any) {
    // topping = this.toppings;
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.toppings);
    console.log(this.toppings);
}
```

**pizza.component.html**

```
<div class="pizza"><div class="toppings" *ngFor="let topping of toppings; let i = index"><div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="content {{ topping }}" [ngStyle]="getMyStyles(i)"></div</div></div><div class="btn btn-success text-align-center (click)="addtoCart(topping)">Add to Cart</div>
```

Comment: What actually not working ?

Comment: cart item list doesn't display on Cart.component.html when i added the pizza to the cart

Comment: Where are you calling the addToCart method from the cart service? Also, can you post the cart.component.html?

Comment: Could you add a bit of the code that isn't working to a runnable Stackblitz? Also, do you need a dynamic component? Or just a pizza "object" that retains it's set of toppings?

Comment: @HristiyanYanev the method will be called on the Button add to cart to add the customized Pizza with its toppings, so basically <Button (click)="addToCart(Pizza)">Add to Cart</Button>

Comment: all I want is: on my Cart Component page, a list of selected pizzas where the user can then see all his choices and can order. so how to pass the selected pizzas to the cart component.html